# Consultar dados em arrays diferentes para relatório

Tags: php, array

Bom para evitar muito processamento no meu Mysql quando gere um relatório, eu prefiro fazer um select simples e colocar em um array, assim tenho mais liberdade para manipular os dados.

Porém eu me deparei com uma dificuldade, onde tenho 3 arrays diferentes, e preciso fazer a ligação dos dados usando o campo `cod` e `cod_produto`.

Alguém sabe como faço isso? Segue abaixo um exemplo bem simples do relatório que estou montando.
Ele est funcional, so falta colocar os 2 últimos campos, onde tenho que consultar em um array diferente.

OBS: Os campos `cod` e `cod_produto` são iguais e não repetem, ou seja cada produto tem o seu código.

```
<?php

// Consulta produtos no BD
$consulta = Query($mysqli, "select cod,nome,unidade,peso from produto");
while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_object($consulta)) {

    // Array com dados dos produtos
    $produtos[] = array(
        "cod" => $resultado->cod,
        "nome" => $resultado->nome,
        "unidade" => $resultado->unidade,
        "peso" => $resultado->peso
    );  
}

// Consulta os valores
$consulta = Query($mysqli, "select cod_produto,valor,desconto,comissao from valores_produto");
while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_object($consulta)) {

    // Array com dados dos produtos
    $valores[] = array(
        "cod_produto" => $resultado->cod_produto,
        "valor" => $resultado->valor,
        "desconto" => $resultado->desconto,
        "comissao" => $resultado->comissao
    );  
}

// Consulta as promoções
$consulta = Query($mysqli, "select cod_produto,valor,desconto,comissao from promocoes_produto");
while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_object($consulta)) {

    // Array com dados dos produtos
    $promocoes[] = array(
        "cod_produto" => $resultado->cod_produto,
        "valor" => $resultado->valor,
        "desconto" => $resultado->desconto,
        "comissao" => $resultado->comissao
    );  
}

// Organiza o array pelo nome
uasort($produtos, function ($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a['nome'], $b['nome']);
});
?>

<table>
    <th>
        <td>COD</td>
        <td>NOME</td>
        <td>UNIDADE</td>
        <td>VALOR</td>
        <td>PROMOÇÃO</td>
    </th>
    <?php
    // Navega pelos elementos do array
    foreach ($produtos as $c) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $c['cod'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $c['nome'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $c['unidade'] ?></td>
            <td>aqui tenho que por o valor do array `valores`</td>
            <td>aqui tenho que por o valor do array `promocoes`</td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Dúvida, esse "cod_produto" é um valor único?

Comment: Sim, cada produto tem o seu. Isso não repete pois é uma chave primária na tabela do BD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o campo "cod_prod"para resolver isso. Nos loops de valores e promoções, em vez de você sempre atribuir o array para uma nova posição, você vai informar a key que será o código do produto, já que o mesmo é um valor único vai funcionar perfeitamente. E na exibição você vai passar o array respectivo($valores, $promocoes) acessando a key com o "cod" do produto e passando o campo que você quer pegar o valor.

```
<?php

    // Consulta produtos no BD
    $consulta = Query($mysqli, "select cod,nome,unidade,peso from produto");
    while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_object($consulta)) {

        // Array com dados dos produtos
        $produtos[] = array(
            "cod" => $resultado->cod,
            "nome" => $resultado->nome,
            "unidade" => $resultado->unidade,
            "peso" => $resultado->peso
        );  
    }

    // Consulta os valores
    $consulta = Query($mysqli, "select cod_produto,valor,desconto,comissao from valores_produto");
    while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_object($consulta)) {

       // Array com dados dos produtos
       $valores[$resultado->cod_produto] = array(
           "cod_produto" => $resultado->cod_produto,
           "valor" => $resultado->valor,
           "desconto" => $resultado->desconto,
           "comissao" => $resultado->comissao
       );  
    }

    // Consulta as promoções
    $consulta = Query($mysqli, "select cod_produto,valor,desconto,comissao from promocoes_produto");
    while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_object($consulta)) {

       // Array com dados dos produtos
       $promocoes[$resultado->cod_produto] = array(
           "cod_produto" => $resultado->cod_produto,
           "valor" => $resultado->valor,
           "desconto" => $resultado->desconto,
           "comissao" => $resultado->comissao
       );  
    }

   // Organiza o array pelo nome
   uasort($produtos, function ($a, $b) {
       return strcmp($a['nome'], $b['nome']);
   });
?>

<table>
    <th>
        <td>COD</td>
        <td>NOME</td>
        <td>UNIDADE</td>
        <td>VALOR</td>
        <td>PROMOÇÃO</td>
    </th>
<?php
    // Navega pelos elementos do array
     foreach ($produtos as $c) { 
         $cod_produto = $c['cod'];
     ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $c['cod'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $c['nome'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $c['unidade'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $valores[$cod_produto]['valor'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $promocoes[$cod_produto]['valor'] ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Hum entendi, tem um erro aqui `$cod_produto = $['cod'];` o certo seria `$cod_produto = $c['cod'];` ?

Comment: Vou testar aqui, jaja te aviso se deu certo e merco sua resposta ok.

Comment: Certo, vou editar e resolver o erro ai.

Comment: Amigo testei aqui e funcionou 100%, muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Por nada meu amigo, boa sorte ai!